# spark streaming checkpoint : Data checkpointing control

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, checkpoint

I have something confused about the spark streaming checkpoint, please help me, thanks!

1. There are two types of checkpointing (Metadata & Data checkpointing). And the guides said when using stateful transformations, data checkpointing is used. I'm very confused about this. If I don't use stateful transformations, does spark still write Data checkpointing content?
2. Can I control the checkpoint position in codes ? 
   Can I control which rdd can be written to data checkpointing data in streaming like batch spark job ? 
   Can I use foreachRDD  `rdd => rdd.checkpoint()` in streaming?
3. If I don't use the `rdd.checkpoint()`, what is the default behavior of Spark? Which rdd can be written to HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

You can find excellent  guide with this [Link](https://github.com/JerryLead/SparkInternals/blob/master/markdown/english/6-CacheAndCheckpoint.md).

1. No, there is no need to checkpoint data, because no intermediate data you need in case of stateless computation.
2. I don't think you need checkpoint any rdd after computation in streaming. The rdd checkpoint is designed to address lineage issue, the streaming checkpoint is all about streaming reliability and failure recovery.

Comment: Thanks! What is the stateless meaning? If I want to count something from the streaming and I don't set checkpoint, the failed tasks will can't restart and the rdds will be lost.